# Why "the reason being is" not just "the reason is"?

Tags: vocabulary, auxiliary-verbs

Source: https://www.searchenginejournal.com/why-start-digital-marketing-agency/385300/#close

> Is a digital marketing agency a good business?
>
> Building out a digital marketing agency is far more productive and
> beneficial versus having only freelance individuals working for you.
> ***The reason being is*** that these people won't be working in siloes, but
> rather be part of a bigger team.

What is the diffirence if the writer had said "The reason is .."?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This article is very, very poorly written, and you caught some of the bad grammar. There's two ways to fix this mistake: your way and the way intended by the speaker.

Your way: *"...working for you. The reason is..."*.

The writer's intention: *"...working for you, the reason being..."*. Note that it's all one sentence now. If you're not familiar with the expression "the reason being", you can look it up.